# Invariant Violation: Could not find "client" in the context or passed in as an option

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-apollo

I have a very simple react native setup which I am trying to connect to a Graphql server through Apollo.

This is what the only file I modified (after CRNA), looks like:

App.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, ScrollView, Text, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { ApolloProvider, useQuery } from '@apollo/client';

import client from './apollo';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

export const FETCH_TODOS = gql`
query {
  todos (
    order_by: {
      created_at: desc
    },
    where: { is_public: { _eq: false} }
  ) {
    id
    title
    is_completed
    created_at
    is_public
    user {
      name
    }
  }
}
`;

const App: () => React.ReactNode = () => {

  const { data, error, loading } = useQuery(
    FETCH_TODOS,
  );

  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <ScrollView
        style={styles.scrollView}>
        <FlatList
          data={data.todos}
          renderItem={({ item }: any) => <Text>{item}</Text>}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
        />
      </ScrollView>
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  scrollView: {
    backgroundColor: "white",
  }
});

export default App;
```

The makeApolloClient file is this:

`apollo.ts`

```
import {
    ApolloClient,
    InMemoryCache,
    NormalizedCacheObject,
    createHttpLink
} from '@apollo/client'

function makeApolloClient({ token }: any): ApolloClient<NormalizedCacheObject> {
    // create an apollo link instance, a network interface for apollo client
    const link = createHttpLink({
        uri: `https://hasura.io/learn/graphql`,
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        }
    });

    const cache = new InMemoryCache()
    const client = new ApolloClient({
        link: link as any,
        cache
    });
    return client;
}

const client = makeApolloClient({ token: "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6Ik9FWTJSVGM1UlVOR05qSXhSRUV5TURJNFFUWXdNekZETWtReU1EQXdSVUV4UVVRM05EazFNQSJ9" });
export default client;
```

On running `npx react-native run-android`, this is the error I get:

```
Invariant Violation: Could not find "client" in the context or passed in as an option. Wrap the root component in an <ApolloProvider>, or pass an ApolloClient instance in via options.
```

Can't figure out what the issue is, since I've already wrapped the only component I have with ApolloProvider.